# Why there is no OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, heap-memory

I can not understand why there is NO OutOfMemoryError in this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] ref = new Object[1];
    while (true) {
        ref[0] = new Object[]{ref};
        ref = (Object[]) ref[0];
    }
}
```

As for me the above mentioned code has to be work on the following way:

```
Start:
   ref = new Object[1];
Loop:
   ref[0] = new Object []{ new Object[1] }
   ref = new Object []{ new Object[1] }
   ref[0] = new Object []{ new Object []{ new Object[1] } }
   ref = new Object []{ new Object []{ new Object[1] } }
```

I mean that links for each new Object are saved and garbage collector cannot delete not used object and consequently there must be OutOfMemoryError. But if code be run, it will work ages...

What I do not understand or where I am wrong? Please explain me.

Comment: Can you check the memory usage of that Process ? It will be growing, but not that fast to be out of memory instantly

Comment: Todays machines have a lot of memory and you don't know the speed of your while loop. If you try to allocate a few million ints in an array at once you will quickly run out of memory, but allocating 1 object reference at a time would take a few million times longer.

Comment: x64 program would take some time to throw OOM :) Also even 32 bit one would take some time to fill 2-4GB with ~30 byte items. You likely just need to wait long enough - so no repro.

Comment: The array has only one place to keep the reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no memory leak here.

Consider the steps:

1. `Object[] ref = new Object[1];`
   Memory: `ref --> array 1`
2. `ref[0] = new Object[]{ref};`
   Memory: `ref --> array 1 --> array 2 --> array 1`
3. `ref = (Object[]) ref[0];`
   Memory: `ref --> array 2 --> array 1 --> array 2 --> ...`
4. `ref[0] = new Object[]{ref};`
   Memory: `ref --> array 2 --> array 3 --> array 2 --> ...`
   ***At this point, `array 1` is no longer referenced, so it can be GC collected.***
5. `ref = (Object[]) ref[0];`
   Memory: `ref --> array 3 --> array 2 --> array 3 --> ...`
6. `ref[0] = new Object[]{ref};`
   Memory: `ref --> array 3 --> array 4 --> array 3 --> ...`
   ***At this point, `array 2` is no longer referenced, so it can be GC collected.***

... and the cycle continues.  After each loop, there is an array that is no longer referenced and that becomes eligible for garbage collection.  As long as the GC does its job, you will never run out of memory.

**EDIT:** Corrected the details of how the arrays are linked in memory. Thanks to Javier for pointing that out.

Comment: But the usage of "ref" in the new Object [] {ref} call refers to array 1, so array 2 refers to array 1.

Comment: No, when creating the array, its contents are initialised with what ref contains *at that point in time*. Just like passing ref to a function and later reassigning it does not change what was passed to the function, altering what ref points to later does not alter what the contents of array 2 refer to.

Comment: @Javier: It took me a while to sort through my confusion.  But you are 100% right.  I adjusted my answer to correct that.  The end result is that there is still one array that is no longer referenced after each loop iteration, but it doesn't happen on the line that I initially thought.

Answer (score 0):

#### Explaining with your own assumption,

```
Start:
   ref = new Object[1];
Loop:
   ref[0] = new Object []{ new Object[1] }
   ref = new Object []{ new Object[1] }
   // at this point ref is re-allocated
   ref[0] = new Object []{ new Object []{ new Object[1] } }
   ref = new Object []{ new Object []{ new Object[1] } }
   // at this point ref is re-allocated
```

At both above mentioned points `ref` is being re-allocated hence previous reference of `ref` is lost. As the `ref` is lost that means java garbage collector is ready to de-reference the memory pointed by the previous `ref`.

#### Thus there is no memory leak in your code